# Blender Version Transition Issue

Tags: versions

I do have a question. When upgrading from 2.79 to 2.80, i receive an error saying that I need to update my old version of [Open-G.L] will not work and needed a [Open-G.l] 3.3 or higher which i don't have, any help to keep the old version in blender will be of help, i do want to try out the sculpting mode in 2.80?

Comment: What GPU do you have? And what OS?

Comment: Please check if your hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x. If your GPU is supported, try to update your graphics driver.